# What does 相殺される refer to here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

> 商人ギルドに店を登録した時にも口添えをしてくれ、商人ギルドから開業資金を借りると、その利子と初年度のギルド会費が相殺されることも教えてくれた。工費がかからなかったとはいえ、貯金は材料費でほとんど持っていかれていたので良かった。初年度のギルド会費が払えず営業権剝奪ということもこれで心配ない。

Does this mean that the interest of the debt will waiver the guild's fee? Or does it mean that both of them will be cancelled?

Answer (score 4):

If I guessed the context correctly, the 利子 and the ギルド会費 are both money that this person has to pay to the guild, right? Then they cannot cancel each other out and become zero, so this use of 相殺 is wrong.

Maybe it means that the guild will waive the ギルド会費 if you pay the 利子, but in that case the correct phrase would be something like その利子の支払いを初年度のギルド会費としても充当できる or その利子を支払うことで初年度のギルド会費が免除される.

Comment: most definitely , because the mc says later  工費がかからなかったとはいえ、貯金は材料費でほとんど持っていかれていたので良かった。初年度のギルド会費が払はらえず営業権剝奪ということもこれで心配ない。

Comment: +1. Although wrong, I'd guess most readers will understand the sentence similarly, without ambiguity.